# C4DROID Makefile issues

Tags: android, c++, makefile

For all you C4DROID dev's, I have a question about the Makefile option.  I have been toying around with it for some time now, and just can't seem to get it to function properly.  I've tried implementing the tutorial from http://mrbook.org/tutorials/make/ as well as http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Implicit-Rules .  These sites have helped me at least get different error messages (which in some ways is helpful) but I'm just not sure what else I need to be doing.  I'm not sure how much detail I should include about what I'm doing (first time posting), so here goes.

At the moment, I have the files (for test purposes only) main.cpp, hello.cpp, factorial.cpp, and functions.h .  I created a Makefile with:

```
all:
  g++ main.cpp hello.cpp factorial.cpp functions.h -o MyFile
```

I have also tried variations like:

```
all: testTwo
  testTwo:
  g++ main.cpp hello.cpp factorial.cpp functions.h -o MyFile
```

In the compilation settings, I have selected Makefile, I have not modified the "Commands Before Make" code (I don't even understand it), my Make command is 
`make -f Makefile`

I have selected the Native Activity in Run Mode, and that's all that I can think of explaining.  My error message I get on compilation is "Failed to copy file".

Any help with the process would be greatly appreciated and thank you in advance.

Comment: I have `C4DROID` on my `SAMSUNG GALAXY NOTE 10.1`.  Why are you trying to `make` the files when the `developer` included a `compile` button? Ensure you are within `main` when `compiling` and, if syntactically correct, should compile.  I have written several programs using `C4DROID` that included multiple compilation and all succeeded fine.

Comment: I went back and recompiled everything together; I guess my confusion came from the app's dev who told me I needed to use Makefile for compiling multiple files.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction, still interested on how to use the Makefile option though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the compile options screen, section 'Result binary filename': enter the name of the executable that your Makefile generates i.e. MyFile for your example.

I also tend to use 'Run mode: Terminal app' for simple console programs.  NativeActivity is intended for Android NDK app development and hence is a bit more involved.